# C++ std::string bug when adding size as string in map

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I found Some thing on
visual studio v143 tools std:c++ lastest
is it bug or something

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
std::string test_str = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345";//55 LEN String
map["test_len"] = test_str.length();
std::cout << map["test_len"]; // 7 on 55 len string
```

EDIT:it's same in all numbers Chrome will work even Content-Lenght is not valid

Comment: You are seeing the character with value 55 in ASCII, aka `'7'`. You probably wanted a `std::unordered_map<std::string, int>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statement

```
map["test_len"] = test_str.length();
```

`std::unordered_map::operator[]` default-constructs a new `std::string` and returns a reference to it which is then assigned to a value of type `size_type`. This assignment invokes [`std::string::operator=(char)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) which interprets integer value `55` as ascii character `7`.

This is a long standing usability bug in `std::string` interface. Examples of the bug:

```
std::string s = test_str.length(); // Compiler error.

std::string s2;
s2 = test_str.length(); // Compiles successfully, std::string interface bug.
s2 = true; // Compiles successfully, std::string interface bug.
s2 = std::ios_base::failbit; // Compiles successfully, std::string and std::ios_base interface bugs.

std::string s3{std::ios_base::failbit, 55, true, 'a'}; // Compiles successfully, std::string interface bug.
std::string s3 = {std::ios_base::failbit, 55, true, 'a'}; // Compiles successfully, std::string interface bug.
```

---

C++17 type-safe way to insert or assign a value into an associative container is:

```
map.insert_or_assign("test_len", test_str.length()); // Compiler error.
map.insert_or_assign("test_len", {std::ios_base::failbit, 55, true, 'a'}); // Compiler error.
map.insert_or_assign("test_len", std::to_string(test_str.length())); // Success.
```

[`std::unordered_map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign) always uses direct-initialization of mapped value to avoid precisely this kind of silent unanticipated type conversion bugs when value type assignment operator has different semantics from its constructor, which breaks the [engineering principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 0):

You try to put `length()` to a `string` -> `string` map. What you need instead is to put `to_string()` of it:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> map;
    std::string test_str = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345";//55 LEN String
    map["test_len"] = std::to_string(test_str.length());
    std::cout << map["test_len"];
}
```

Note that `std::string` does have a ctor from a char, as in Maxim's answer, hence your code is not an error, just not what you expected it to be.